# S-shaped Reverse Logistic Curve

Tags: functions, plane-curves

Is there any curve that grows very slow at the beginning then growth picks up exponentially before hitting the wall.
I need sort of reverse behavior of [the logistic curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

Here's raw idea how it should look like [image: http://postimg.org/image/xe1c1p3bl/] (drawn with paint)

And here it is compared with logistic curve [image: http://postimg.org/image/f5uhhecfv/]

Comment: The logistic curve grows slowly at first, then faster before eventually hitting a limit. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Here's a visual example comparing logistic curve and what I need http://postimg.org/image/f5uhhecfv/

Comment: Is an odd-degree polynomial sufficient (see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^7))? What are the exact characteristics you are looking for

Comment: I need y to be 0 when x equals 0. I need symmetric minimum and maximum for y, regardless of size of x ( I think the correct term is asymptotic, described as for minimum  y = -n, maximum y = n) . And I need slow growth for absolute of y when x is close to zero, while growth rises exponentially the further you go from x = 0 .

Comment: @AlexR I believe odd-degree polynomial will do. I will add limits myself. Thank you.

Comment: Just literally do what you're saying: reverse the logistic. The inverse function of the logistic is $\ln \frac{x}{x-1}$.

Comment: Try $\tan(x)$? It approximately gives you the function you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
\begin{align*}
f: (-6,6) &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto \frac{\log(\frac{1}{2}\left(1+x/6)\right)}{1-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+x/6)\right)},
\end{align*}

which is just an adaptation from the one found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), seems to satisfy your needs. (The adaptation is done in order to conform with the interval in your image.) From this you may be able to make further modifications which are relevant to you, if needed.

Looking for the same thing too. This looks promising.

Comment: Is there a function which similar yet on the range [0, 1] gets the values [0, 1] (Like the Logistic function)?

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

$\frac{(x-1/2)\sqrt{1 - k/4}}{\sqrt{1 - k(x-1/2)^{2}}}+1/2$

You can increase or decrease the slope by varying k between $0 < k < 4$

Comment: Nice. Grapher: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v30l6tojjs

Answer (score 1):

`y = 0.5 + log(x / (1-x)) / 4`

Where `4` is a number that determines the "sharpness" of the curve.
Of couse this never *actually* touches 0 and/or 1, so there should be edge cases to protect against `INF` and `-INF`.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8tlyhintnb

@andy-piper's solution is better.
Example graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b0csrdelta